# postgresql update column with least value of column from another table based on condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to run an update query on the column `answer_date` of a table `P`. I want to fill each row of `answer_date` of `P` with the unique date from `create_date` column of `H` where `P.ID1` matches with `H.ID1` and where `P.acceptance_date` is not empty.

The query takes a long while to run, so I check the interim changes in `answer_date` but the entire column is empty like it was created.

Btree indices exists on all the mentioned columns.

Is there something wrong with the query?

```
UPDATE P
SET    answer_date = subquery.date
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT H.create_date as date
        FROM H, P
        where H.postid=P.acceptance_id
    ) AS subquery

WHERE P.acceptance_id is not null;
```

Table schema is as follows:

```
                                              Table "public.P"
        Column         |            Type             | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description
-----------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                    | integer                     | not null  | plain    |              |
 acceptance_id         | integer                     |           | plain    |              |
 answer_date           | timestamp without time zone |           | plain    |              |
Indexes:
    "posts_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "posts_accepted_answer_id_idx" btree (acceptance_id) WITH (fillfactor='100')
```

and

```
                                     Table "public.H"
      Column       |            Type             | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description
-------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                | integer                     | not null  | plain    |              |
 postid            | integer                     |           | plain    |              |
 create_date       | timestamp without time zone | not null  | plain    |              |
Indexes:
    "H_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "ph_creation_date_idx" btree (create_date) WITH (fillfactor='100')
```

Table `P` as 70 million rows and `H` has 220 million rows.

Postgres version is 9.6
Hardware is a Windows laptop with 8Gb of RAM.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function! It's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT`, and applies to the whole selected rows. (`select distinct (c1), c2...` eq.  `select distinct c1, c2...` eq. `select distinct c1, (c2)...` etc.)

Comment: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: @jarlh can you flesh it out in an answer ?

Comment: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name explain (analyze, buffers) is still running. Added the other details, please see.

Comment: Try something like `update p set ... (select min(create_date) from h where h.postid=p.acceptance_id) where ...`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name like this ? `UPDATE P
SET    answer_date = (SELECT MIN(H.create_date)
        FROM H, P
        where H.postid=P.acceptance_id
    )

WHERE P.acceptance_id is not null;`